# Series of books set in space behind enemy lines

Tags: story-identification, books, military-sf

There were a series of books (I think there were 5 when I started reading them) primarily set around a captain whose ship is destroyed at the beginning of a war and escapes in a evacuation pod. He is put into cryosleep and his escape pod is damaged during his escape so his pod is never recovered. Fast forward 100 years (I think, can't exactly remember), the war is still waging and his pod is finally picked up by a friendly (luckily!) fleet.

Following the execution of the current commander of the fleet he is instantly promoted to commander. The fleet is deep behind enemies lines and due to decades of fighting, strict military regulations have degraded. Because of his understanding and expertise with advanced tactics and the loss of such tactics by combatants of the war, he and the fleet are able to carve a path back home.

I never actually finished the series and can't find any of the books anywhere (and obviously can't remember what they're called). I thinks its a fairly new series, perhaps from around the turn of the century, maybe later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [The Lost Fleet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Fleet) by Jack Campbell.

The first book in the series starts almost exactly as you describe.
There's 6 or 7 books in the series and 2 spin-off series (Beyond the Frontier, technically a continuation) and The Lost Stars (told from the enemy's POV).

Comment: HAHA, right, that's exactly it, Thanks!

Comment: ...Crap, through skimming down the wiki page, I've accidentally spoiled the fact that aliens come up later in the story :/

Comment: I'm not much of a writing snob but I find the quality of writing on this to be lower than the norm for what I read.  Yet I'm still very eager to read each one when it gets published!

Comment: @Jim2B I agree, I think the writing isn't brilliant and its a little repetitive but I really like the more scientific approach to space flight and combat. The involvement of the lag as light travels across a solar system and the fact that there are only fractional firing windows as two ship flash by each other at sub light speeds adds really cool dynamics. And later it has _actual_ aliens that are friendly!!!